# Securely pass session to browser from OAuth'd app

Tags: node.js, api, session, authentication, oauth

This is quite a conceptional question, but I'm also interested in implementation details.

Let's say I have an API written in Node.js.

Clients (primarily an iOS app) authenticate via OAuth and then use the session token to authorize each following request.

I now want to point from the app to a browser based web app and take over the authenticated session.

This should, of course, be highly secure and must not be vulnarable in a theoretic sense, but as far as possible in an implementation wise thinking.

I must, somehow, ensure that the request comes from the same device and user, etc.

I thought of generating a short valid token that the client must send, but also this does not seem quite secure when having in mind the TLS protected API.

Comment: what do you mean by a session token in case of the app oauth login? which oauth flow is this? Also, how are you suggesting to share the session token from app to browser? by sending it in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be more secure than OAuth.

From OAuth's perspective, whomever possess the token, is authorised to act on the user's behalf. You may wish to include a secondary secret or verify the IP but I doubt it will do much for you in practice:

If the platform you are on (e.g. iOS) is not compromised, than the OAuth token will be entropy enough to confirm the user's identity. If the platform IS compromised, then any secret your application can set can also be extracted by the assumed attacker.

Comment: Okay, so a working implementation would be fairly straight forward, but not _really_ secure.
When thinking of SSL an co. I'm fearing that "matching IP addresses" is still quite insecure. I also don't want to simply pass the session token to Safari using a GET variable...

Comment: So I would need something like a transaction token and the client must somehow be authenticated. So it seems I need to either, "annoy" the user by presenting him a credentials dialog again, or run an insecure setup. Is this summery appropriate? Also, any better ideas for a workaround?

Comment: By your definition of insecure, OAuth itself is insecure. It plainly passes the session token as a GET parameter without further security measures. If that is not enough for your purposes, you must use an entirely different authentication scheme. If the webapp called in Safari uses SSL, the only way to sniff the token would be to take over the device. Someone able to do so can take over the session anyway.